# (node:8196) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Tags: node.js, express, spdy

I am facing this problem when switching from HTTP to spdy HTTP/2 and I got this warning! Any solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy/issues/382

not yet addressed. but spdy project is not updated for long time. expect this issue will be open for long time as contributors are not active.